# How to debug the error "bonmin.exe has stopped working"

Tags: memory, nonlinear-optimization, pyomo, ampl, ipopt

I am trying to solve a multiple integer non linear programming problem. I have about 178848 decision variables and they are all binary. I am creating the `.nl` file from `pyomo` and then trying to solve this `.nl` file through command prompt with the command: `bonmin test.nl`

Before I get the error in the title, I see a sudden jump in memory wherein I see the memory usage jumping upto 100% before the program exits. Is there any settings I can pass to bonmin to prevent this error from happening? Or is there any heuristic options available which I can pass to bonmin?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a rather large integer program. Solvers have limitations, so it may simply be that Bonmin/CBC cannot handle a problem of that size with the available memory on your system due to the branch and bound tree getting too large. If there are any reformulations or preprocessing possible to reduce the problem size, you may want to try that before sending to Bonmin. You can also try giving branching priority settings, though I am less familiar with how up implement that.

Comment: I agree that memory is a likely culprit here. One way to test that might be to try the same code on a small problem (e.g. constrain most of the decision variables) and check whether the error still appears.